# Copying a view from another list works in PS but not in C#

Tags: view

I'm running this code to copy views from a list to another:

```
foreach (SPView vw in listTempl.Views)
{
    SPView thisVw = myList.Views[vw.Title];
    if (thisVw == null)
    {
         myList.Views.Add(vw.Title, vw.ViewFields.ToStringCollection(),
             vw.Query, vw.RowLimit, vw.Paged, vw.DefaultView);
    }
}
```

The code should run within an Event Receiver.
Indeed it doesn't get executed past the if() part: when it comes to a view which is not present in the target list, code interrupts in some way (the event receiver is not executed past that).

Same code (properly adapted) in powershell runs OK:

```
foreach ($vw in $listTempl.Views)
{
    $thisVw = $myList.Views[$vw.Title];
    if ($thisVw -eq $null)
    {
        $myList.Views.Add($vw.Title, $vw.ViewFields.ToStringCollection(),
                            $vw.Query, $vw.RowLimit, $vw.Paged, $vw.DefaultView);
    }
}
```

I put a breakpoint at the if() line: it is reached for every existing view (eg. the default ones) but it seems to be even skipped for new views.

I tried checking for null view.Title instead of the view itself, with no luck.

I think I am approaching in a wrong way, could you give me any hint?

Comment: Put a breakpoint @ the line SPView thisVw = myItem.Views[vw.Title] in C# and check the value of  myItem.Views by adding it to a watch. That should give you a hint on why you are not able to find the view.

Comment: Is myItem a list item or is it a list?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using a cached version of `SPWeb` object. Try creating new `SPWeb` object and retrieving `SPList` and `SPViews`.

Also try recycling SharePoint Timer Service.

Comment: the C# code would run within an EventReceiver.
Should I use the "using SPWeb..." syntax?